# VB.NET to C# conversion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, converters

I am trying to convert a piece of code to C#, but I cannot get my head around it:

```
For iItem = LBound(arrItems) To UBound(arrItems)
    If InStr(arrItems(iItem), strFieldName & "=") = 1 Then
        strFindField = Mid(arrItems(iItem), Len(strFieldName) + 2)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

What's up with the `if` statement?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you getting any errors with your current attempt at a solution?  Have you used an online converter?  Are you familiar with C# or VB at all?

Comment: As to why you're being downvoted, I would assume it's because you've demonstrated no attempt to solve the problem yourself, you have also not put effort into the question itself.  It's little more than a code block with "do it for me".  Laziness is frequently met with downvotes.

Comment: I also don't really appreciate you not even saying what the loop is supposed to do.

Comment: @YYY What makes you assume that he downvoted it?  I downvoted it because it has several flaws.

Comment: @Servy The reputation changes fooled me, and the lack of a comment seemed consistent.  Of course, your comment showed up just now, so now that I know what's wrong I can actually fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tool doesn't seem to produce very idiomatic C#, so I will translate this for you manually to provide a contrast.

```
foreach (var item in arrItems)
{
   if(item.IndexOf(strFieldName + "=") == 0)
   {
      strFindField = item.Substring(strFieldName.Length + 2);
      break;
   }
}
```

This should mimic what you're doing here, but it's a little difficult to tell what the intent of your loop is.  Also, be aware that `.Substring` will throw an exception if you feed it a number that is out of its range, while `Mid` will just return an empty string.  Since it's not clear how the return for this loop is being used, though, it's difficult to say what is the most appropriate option for handling this semantic change.

Comment: you cannot break from a foreach can you?

Comment: oh yes i think its the other version ForEach that cant be exited.

Comment: `if(item.IndexOf(strFieldName + "=") == 1)` should be `if(item.IndexOf(strFieldName + "=") == 0)`.  VB is 1 indexed, C# is 0 indexed.  You'll also need to do some bounds checking on the substring to ensure that the string is sufficiently long in order to mimic `Mid`, which would return an empty string if the index is past the end of the string, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: VB is 1-indexed, VB.Net is 0-indexed

Comment: @Servy Good catch on the string addressing changes; I haven't worked in vb.net in a long time so I forgot that.  I'll add a note about the differences in handling as far as `Mid` goes, but I'm unsure how to handle that since the question doesn't establish the context.  It could be that the empty string is being used as a control later on in the loop, or that could be a logic error.

Comment: @Basic VB is 1 indexed, VB.NET can be either 1 indexed or 0 indexed based on a project setting; the default setting is for it to be 1 indexed.

Comment: @Servy Then I've somehow missed that setting for years. CAn you indicate where it's hidden?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (iItem = Information.LBound(arrItems); iItem <= Information.UBound(arrItems); iItem++) {
    if (Strings.InStr(arrItems(iItem), strFieldName + "=") == 1) {
        strFindField = Strings.Mid(arrItems(iItem), Strings.Len(strFieldName) + 2);
        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
    }
}
```

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: is mid and instr a function in c# too

Comment: I get "The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current " even though have added using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Strings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `Mid`, `Len`, and `InStr` do not exist in C#, at least not through that syntax.  You would use `Length` as a property of the instance of the string to get it's length, `IndexOf` as an instance method rather than `InStr`, and `Mid` doesn't have a direct port at all.  It's more or less `SubString` but with different support for out of bounds indexes, and I think a slightly different configuration of parameters (as well as also being an instance method, not a static method).

Comment: `Strings` is a uniquely Visual Basic thing, you will have to use more idiomatic C# unless you want to import a bunch of visual basic related assemblies.  For `InStr`, for example, you'll be looking at `String.IndexOf`.